Why is this error appearing in my android flutter app?
I am developing an app that includes AI. After I added it, the app does not launch and crashes.
I'm using Android studio as my IDE I have java 11 installed. I have messed around with a few settings files on my project but i don't think that that's causing the crashes as I always did it with caution
ERROR LOG:
Launching lib\main.dart on 22111317PG in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
E/AndroidRuntime(31832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31832): Process: com.example.style_ai_demo, PID: 31832
E/AndroidRuntime(31832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.style_ai_demo/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~wgtxWxcNPkXk2gF2NAzX5g==/com.example.style_ai_demo-DSNTGPTEropC3oZV8dIXMw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~wgtxWxcNPkXk2gF2NAzX5g==/com.example.style_ai_demo-DSNTGPTEropC3oZV8dIXMw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~wgtxWxcNPkXk2gF2NAzX5g==/com.example.style_ai_demo-DSNTGPTEropC3oZV8dIXMw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3898)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4144)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2589)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8780)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:561)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~wgtxWxcNPkXk2gF2NAzX5g==/com.example.style_ai_demo-DSNTGPTEropC3oZV8dIXMw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~wgtxWxcNPkXk2gF2NAzX5g==/com.example.style_ai_demo-DSNTGPTEropC3oZV8dIXMw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~wgtxWxcNPkXk2gF2NAzX5g==/com.example.style_ai_demo-DSNTGPTEropC3oZV8dIXMw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1390)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3882)
E/AndroidRuntime(31832):    ... 12 more

Also here are all my files
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/face_analysis_page.dart';
import 'pages/choose_style_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AI Style Assistant',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.purple),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => FaceAnalysisPage(),
        '/chooseStyle': (context) => FaceAnalysisPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

pages\face_analysis_page.dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FaceAnalysisPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FaceAnalysisPageState createState() => _FaceAnalysisPageState();
}

class _FaceAnalysisPageState extends State<FaceAnalysisPage> {
  File? _imageFile;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  String _analysisResult = "";

  // Function to pick an image from the gallery
  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
      await _analyzeImage(_imageFile!);
    }
  }

  // Function to analyze image using Google Vision API
  Future<void> _analyzeImage(File imageFile) async {
    final String apiKey = "AIzaSyAaYpd3twtEXKbAsUX2ZOJGfz2ErBqHEng";
    final String url =
        "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=$apiKey";

    // Convert image to base64
    final imageBytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
    final base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);

    // Prepare API request payload
    final Map<String, dynamic> requestPayload = {
      "requests": [
        {
          "image": {"content": base64Image},
          "features": [
            {"type": "FACE_DETECTION"},
            {"type": "LABEL_DETECTION"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: jsonEncode(requestPayload),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        setState(() {
          _analysisResult = _parseAnalysisResult(jsonResponse);
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _analysisResult = "Error: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.reasonPhrase}";
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _analysisResult = "Error: $e";
      });
    }
  }

  // Function to parse analysis result
  String _parseAnalysisResult(Map<String, dynamic> result) {
    final faceAnnotations = result["responses"][0]["faceAnnotations"];
    if (faceAnnotations == null || faceAnnotations.isEmpty) {
      return "No faces detected.";
    }

    final firstFace = faceAnnotations[0];
    final emotions = {
      "Joy": firstFace["joyLikelihood"],
      "Sorrow": firstFace["sorrowLikelihood"],
      "Anger": firstFace["angerLikelihood"],
      "Surprise": firstFace["surpriseLikelihood"],
    };

    String emotionSummary = "Detected Emotions:\n";
    emotions.forEach((key, value) {
      emotionSummary += "$key: $value\n";
    });

    return """
Face Analysis:
$emotionSummary
""";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AI Face Analysis'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            if (_imageFile != null)
              Image.file(
                _imageFile!,
                height: 200,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _pickImage,
              child: Text('Pick an Image for Analysis'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text(
              _analysisResult,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/chooseStyle');
              },
              child: Text('Next: Choose Style'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

pages\first_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Start Your Scan'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/begin_scan.jpeg', // Replace with your actual image asset
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 500.0, // Adjust the height for proper scaling
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0), // Add spacing between image and button
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/takePicture');
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0), // Adjust button size
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'BEGIN YOUR SCAN HERE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

pages\take_video_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'choose_style_page.dart';
import 'face_analysis_page.dart'; // Import the new page

class TakeVideoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TakeVideoPageState createState() => _TakeVideoPageState();
}

class _TakeVideoPageState extends State<TakeVideoPage> {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  File? _recordedVideo;
  VideoPlayerController? _videoPlayerController;
  bool _videoTaken = false;

  // Function to record a video using the camera
  Future<void> _recordVideo() async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _recordedVideo = File(pickedFile.path);
        _videoTaken = true;
        _initializeVideoPlayer(); // Initialize the video player when a video is recorded
      });
    }
  }

  // Function to initialize the video player
  void _initializeVideoPlayer() {
    if (_recordedVideo != null) {
      _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_recordedVideo!)
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          setState(() {}); // Update UI after initialization
        });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController?.dispose(); // Dispose of the controller to free resources
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Take a Video'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                child: _videoTaken && _videoPlayerController != null
                    ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController!),
                )
                    : Image.asset(
                  'assets/take_video.jpeg', // Replace with your actual placeholder image
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 500.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _recordVideo, // Trigger video recording
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: _videoTaken ? Colors.green : Colors.purple,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  _videoTaken
                      ? 'Video Taken Successfully!'
                      : 'Take a Video of Your Body',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (_videoTaken)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_videoPlayerController != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        _videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                            ? _videoPlayerController!.pause()
                            : _videoPlayerController!.play();
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    _videoPlayerController != null &&
                        _videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                        ? 'Pause Video'
                        : 'Play Video',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            if (_videoTaken)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Navigate to the ChooseClothingPage
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => FaceAnalysisPage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Continue to Clothing Options',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

pages\choose_style_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class ChooseStylePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChooseStylePageState createState() => _ChooseStylePageState();
}

class _ChooseStylePageState extends State<ChooseStylePage> {
  String? _selectedStyle;
  final List<String> _styles = ["Elegant", "Casual", "Stylish", "Surprise Me"];

  void _chooseRandomStyle() {
    final random = Random();
    setState(() {
      _selectedStyle = _styles[random.nextInt(_styles.length - 1)];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Choose Your Style'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            DropdownButton<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              value: _selectedStyle,
              items: _styles.map((style) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: style,
                  child: Text(style),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                if (value == "Surprise Me") {
                  _chooseRandomStyle();
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedStyle = value;
                  });
                }
              },
              hint: Text("Select your style"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text(
              "Selected Style: ${_selectedStyle ?? "None"}",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Any help is appreciated

Is the activity mentioned (com.example.myapp.MainActivity) found in your AndroidManifest.xml?

no I did not find it there

Then that is the origin of your issue. You need to make sure that the activity is found inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.

The error you're encountering (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MainActivity") is typically caused by the Android project not being properly configured or by a mismatch between your AndroidManifest.xml and the Flutter project structure. Specifically, it looks like the Android app is unable to find the main activity (MainActivity) that should be defined in your Flutter project.
1. Verify Wrong Package Name or Class Name in AndroidManifest.xml
Check your 'AndroidManifest.xml' file (located at 'android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml') to ensure that it has the correct 'MainActivity' entry:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|fontScale"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Ensure that the android:name=".MainActivity" line points to the correct main activity class, which should be in the com.example.style_ai_demo package (or whatever your app's package name is).
2. Verify Your Flutter Package and Application Class
In Flutter, the MainActivity should be located in the android/app/src/main/java/com/example/style_ai_demo/MainActivity.java or MainActivity.kt file. Verify that the MainActivity file exists and contains the correct FlutterActivity subclass.
Here’s an example of what MainActivity.java should look like for a Flutter project:
package com.example.style_ai_demo

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}

3. Verify Gradle Build Configuration
If you modified the Gradle files or other project settings, there might be a build configuration issue. Make sure that your Flutter project is set up correctly with the right minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and compileSdkVersion.
Open your android/build.gradle file and check the minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and compileSdkVersion. For example:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.style_ai_demo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}

Also, ensure that the dependencies' section in your android/app/build.gradle` file has the correct versions of the required dependencies.
4. Clean and Rebuild the Project
Sometimes, the build process might get stuck with an old configuration. To fix this, you can clean and rebuild the project:
flutter clean; flutter run

5. Ensure Flutter and Gradle Versions Are Compatible
Make sure you're using compatible versions of Flutter and Gradle. If you recently upgraded Flutter or made changes to your project structure, it’s a good idea to update the Gradle wrapper. You can do this by running the following command in the terminal:
flutter upgrade

Also, ensure that your gradle-wrapper.properties (located at android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties) points to a valid Gradle version. For example:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip

6. Check for Package/Module Renaming Issues
If you've renamed your project or changed the package structure, you might have overlooked updating the package name in certain places. Double check the following:

AndroidManifest.xml: Ensure the package attribute in the <manifest> tag matches your app's package name.
MainActivity.java or MainActivity.kt: Make sure that the package declaration at the top of the file corresponds to the correct package.
gradle.properties and build.gradle: Ensure the application ID in these files is consistent.

7. Check for AI-related Dependencies
If the app was working before you added AI functionality, there could be an issue with a dependency or a conflict. To check if the AI-related code is causing issues, you can temporarily remove or comment out the AI-related dependencies and code, then try running the app again. If it runs without errors, then the issue might be caused by a conflict or misconfiguration related to the AI integration.

Hi Furqan. It looks like you've generated this answer using an AI assistant, such as ChatGPT. Note that posting content generated by AI assistants is not allowed on Stack Overflow. Read more about this policy here. Please delete any and all answers you've generated using AI assistants from Stack Overflow please. By the looks of it, the other answers you've just posted on Stack Overflow were generated by AI assistants too, so please delete those too. Thank you.

AI generated answer is prohibited.
